# Cloudsearch dynamic fields skipping fields

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

In cloudsearch (using IMDB data) I added two dynamic fields to the existing indexing options
[image: in the indexing options]

I then got the entire JSON IMDB data from AWS and added the fields `location_t` and `month_i`.

```
[{
"fields": {
    "rating": 7.4,
    "genres": ["Comedy", "Drama"],
    "plot": "A New Jersey guy dedicated to his family, friends, and church, develops unrealistic expectations from watching porn and works to find happiness and intimacy with his potential true love.",
    "release_date": "2013-01-18T00:00:00Z",
    "title": "Don Jon",
    "rank": 1,
    "running_time_secs": 5400,
    "directors": ["Joseph Gordon-Levitt"],
    "image_url": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQxNTc3NDM2MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNzQ5NTQ3OQ@@._V1_SX400_.jpg",
    "year": 2013,
    "actors": ["Joseph Gordon-Levitt", "Scarlett Johansson", "Julianne Moore"]
},
"type": "add",
"id": "tt2229499",
"location_t": "Berlin",
"month_i": 8},...
```

When I uploaded the JSON, it ignored the dynamic fields? 
[image]

I did it anyway and I tried searching but to no avail. Anyone no what I am doing wrong. I followed the [instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/using-dynamic-fields.html) to the book in dynamic fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have your dynamic fields as a part of your `fields` array, see below:

```
[{
"fields": {
    "rating": 7.4,
    "genres": ["Comedy", "Drama"],
    "plot": "A New Jersey guy dedicated to his family, friends, and church, develops unrealistic expectations from watching porn and works to find happiness and intimacy with his potential true love.",
    "release_date": "2013-01-18T00:00:00Z",
    "title": "Don Jon",
    "rank": 1,
    "running_time_secs": 5400,
    "directors": ["Joseph Gordon-Levitt"],
    "image_url": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQxNTc3NDM2MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNzQ5NTQ3OQ@@._V1_SX400_.jpg",
    "year": 2013,
    "actors": ["Joseph Gordon-Levitt", "Scarlett Johansson", "Julianne Moore"],
    "location_t": "Berlin",
    "month_i": 8
},
"type": "add",
"id": "tt2229499",},...
```